# Instagram API Tagging Error Using Python

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to print out all the caption text that have 'Starhub' in
 it. It works, but I only able to print out a total of 19 text.

Found this function: api.tag_recent_media(count, max_tag_id, tag_name)
 - https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

So I make use of that function, but it failed. I type 50 counts
 meaning I hope that 50 text would come out, but it only print out 19
 instead.

My codes:

```
 from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
 from instagram.bind import InstagramAPIError

 access_token = "<TOKEN>"
 client_secret = "<SECRET>"

 api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
 recent_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media(count=50, tag_name="Starhub")

 count = 0

 for media in recent_media:       try:
      print media.caption.text, "--->", media.user.username
      print ""
       count += 1
          except UnicodeEncodeError:
      pass

 print count
```

This code print out only 19. So what I try to do instead is this.

I add this inside my code:

```
 while next_:    
   more_media, next_ =api.tag_recent_media(with_next_url=next_)     
   recent_media.extend(more_media)
```

There is error: No paremeter value found for path variable; tag_name.

Any idea how can I print out all text that have the tag 'Starhub'?

Comment: Are you sure that there are more than 19 Results? Maybe you get only 19 because there are really only 19.

Comment: I tried other tags like Samsung and Apple, only receive 19 tags.

Comment: This Answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18452274/2927205